# Regular Expression is not working using onkeyup function

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```
$(function(){
    $('#addAction').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#extras').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-1">Delivery Fee: </div><input id="price_' + count + '" name="prices[]' + '" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, \'\');" /></div>' );
    });
});
```

I don't know why regular expression is not replacing the value by empty string. if someone want to add alphabet value in numeric field, then alphabet value should be remove from numeric field, but I tried, it is not working, kindly tell me the proper solution.

Comment: What it work when the code is in the original HTML rather than injected?

Comment: yes it is working, but I append this value to id by javascript, then it does not work, I have issue of concatenation, the issue have in single comma, when we use in javascript

Answer (score 2):

`javascript:` is only needed for the `href` attribute of anchor elements.

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what that regex is supposed to do, but I am assuming that you're trying to only allow numbers in the input field. A better way to do this is to check the `Event.keyCode` property and use `Event.preventDefault()` to disallow any non-numeric characters.

You should refrain from using inline JavaScript, it is not maintainable and will lead to issues later on.

You can use apply the `onkeyup` event listener using [`jQuery.keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) in this situation.

```js
$(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $('#addAction').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        var newRow = $('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-1">Delivery Fee: </div><input id="price_' + count + '" name="prices[]' + '" type="text"></div>');
        $('#price_' + count, newRow).keydown(function(event){
            var charCode = event.keyCode;
            if (!(charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) 
             && !(charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        $('#extras').append(newRow);
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="addAction">Click Me</button>
<div id="extras"></div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: FYI: expression should be `[^0-9]` not `[0-9]`.

Comment: Changed, after reading the question again, that was not what they were looking for (and generally a bad way of going about it)